Azure Logic App provisioned from Terraform throwing BadRequest & API error problem
I have a set of virtual machines I would like to automatically turn on in the morning. I have provisioned a logic app that automatically turns on the virtual machines, here is my code:
# Logic App Workflow
resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "logic_app" {
  name                = "vm-startup-logicapp"
  location            = "xxx"
  resource_group_name = "xxx"
}

# Recurrence Trigger
resource "azurerm_logic_app_trigger_recurrence" "recurrence" {
  logic_app_id = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.logic_app.id
  name         = "daily-trigger"
  frequency    = "Day"
  interval     = 1
  time_zone    = "Pacific Standard Time"
  
  schedule {
    at_these_hours   = [7]
    at_these_minutes = [0]
  }
}

# Common Headers
locals {
  headers = {
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
    "Authorization" = "Bearer ${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.access_token.value}"
  }
}

# HTTP Action to start VM devinfrajbox01
resource "azurerm_logic_app_action_http" "start_vm_action_jbox01" {
  logic_app_id = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.logic_app.id
  name         = "start-vm-devinfrajbox01"
  method       = "POST"
  uri          = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/devinfrajbox01/start?api-version=2024-07-01"
  headers      = local.headers
}

# HTTP Action to start VM devinfrajbox02
resource "azurerm_logic_app_action_http" "start_vm_action_jbox02" {
  logic_app_id = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.logic_app.id
  name         = "start-vm-devinfrajbox02"
  method       = "POST"
  uri          = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/devinfrajbox02/start?api-version=2024-07-01"
  headers      = local.headers
}

# HTTP Action to start VM devinfrarunner02
resource "azurerm_logic_app_action_http" "start_vm_action_runner02" {
  logic_app_id = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.logic_app.id
  name         = "start-vm-devinfrarunner02"
  method       = "POST"
  uri          = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/devinfrarunner02/start?api-version=2024-07-01"
  headers      = local.headers
}

This logic app keeps giving me 'BadRequest's that fail immediately and say:
{
"error": {
"code": "MissingApiVersionParameter",
"message": "The api-version query parameter (?api-version=) is required for all requests."
}
}
I have followed the documentation letter by letter and am still getting this error message. For reason it's telling me it requires an API parameter when the API parameter is present. I have also used LLMs extensively and still no solution. Any help appreciated.


Azure Logic App provisioned from Terraform throwing Bad Request & API error

The issue in your configuration is might be with the way you called the Api version I tried the same configuration from my so that we will be able to achieve the requirement you're looking for.
Configuration:
resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "logic_app" {
  name                = "vm-startup-logicapp"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_logic_app_trigger_recurrence" "recurrence" {
  logic_app_id = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.logic_app.id
  name         = "daily-trigger"
  frequency    = "Day"
  interval     = 1
  time_zone    = "Pacific Standard Time"
  
  schedule {
    at_these_hours   = [7]
    at_these_minutes = [0]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "key_vault" {
  name                = "testvksskeyvault"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  tenant_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name            = "standard"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "access_token" {
  name         = "access-token"
  value        = "Intel@9959631237"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
}

locals {
  headers = {
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
    "Authorization" = "Bearer ${azurerm_key_vault_secret.access_token.value}"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_logic_app_action_http" "start_vm_action" {
  logic_app_id = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.logic_app.id
  name         = "start-vm-action"
  method       = "POST"
  uri          = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_client_config.current.subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/${azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm.name}/start?api-version=2024-07-01"
  headers      = local.headers
}

deployment:



Refer:
azurerm_logic_app_action_http | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtual-machines/start?view=rest-compute-2024-07-01&tabs=HTTP
